# Upload saved image to docker

Tags: docker

I've an image from another repo I'd like to upload to my docker repo.

I've managed to save it:

```
docker save <imageId> -o mydockersimage.tar
```

Now how can I upload this image to my public repo? Sorry if that's dumb, I'm getting started with docker

Comment: What do you mean by "my public repo" ? Please provide more details what you try to achieve

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to push a docker image to a private repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28349392/how-to-push-a-docker-image-to-a-private-repository)

Comment: No, @Rao, this question is 1) about pushing to a private repo 2) an image already tagged

Comment: Yes, that was to push to a private repo only. Any way, looks you got answer already.

Comment: indeed I got the response I needed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow these steps:

Load the image:

```
docker load < busybox.tar.gz
```

Verify:

```
docker images
```

Tag the image (note image id from output of previous step):

```
docker tag 7d9495d03763 yourusername/yourimagename:latest
```

Login:

```
docker login
```

Push the image:

```
docker push yourusername/yourimagename
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to upload an image to a repository you should tag your image

```
docker tag [initial-image] [reponame]\[imagename]:[tag]
```

and then push it

```
docker push [reponame]\[imagename]:[tag]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to put your image to a new computer you can import this image
copy the mydockersimage.tar to the new computer and do

```
docker import /path/to/mydockersimage.tar
```

But I thing it not a good practice I encourage you to do a push like my previous answer.