# What is the correct upload URL for a Dockerhub repo

Tags: docker, dockerhub, azure-iot-edge, microsoft-custom-vision

I am following the instructions for the [custom-vision service on raspberry-pi on IOT edge](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/Custom-vision-service-iot-edge-raspberry-pi).

I have reached step 3, where in VS Code I am executing `Build and Push to IOT Edge Solution` and this is triggering the following command:

```
docker build  --rm -f "/Users/myname/Dropbox/Dev/azure/custom-vision/Custom-vision-service-iot-edge-raspberry-pi/modules/CameraCapture/arm32v7.Dockerfile" -t registry.hub.docker.com/v1/repositories/myname/iot-hub-1/cameracapture:0.2.7-arm32v7 "/Users/myname/Dropbox/Dev/azure/custom-vision/Custom-vision-service-iot-edge-raspberry-pi/modules/CameraCapture" 
&& docker push registry.hub.docker.com/v1/repositories/myname/iot-hub-1/cameracapture:0.2.7-arm32v7 
&& docker build  --rm -f "/Users/myname/Dropbox/Dev/azure/custom-vision/Custom-vision-service-iot-edge-raspberry-pi/modules/ImageClassifierService/arm32v7.Dockerfile" -t registry.hub.docker.com/v1/repositories/myname/iot-hub-1/imageclassifierservice:0.2.4-arm32v7 "/Users/myname/Dropbox/Dev/azure/custom-vision/Custom-vision-service-iot-edge-raspberry-pi/modules/ImageClassifierService" 
&& docker push registry.hub.docker.com/v1/repositories/myname/iot-hub-1/imageclassifierservice:0.2.4-arm32v7
```

Which is failing with `404 - page not found`.

I also tried using `cloud.docker.com/repository/registry-1.docker.io/myname/iot-hub-1` but this gave me a different error:

> invalid argument
>   "cloud.docker.com/repository/docker/myname/iot-hub-1:latest/cameracapture:0.2.7-arm32v7"
>   for "-t, --tag" flag: invalid reference format

Can anyone assist with the correct URL path, or some the additional steps i need to uploading the containers to my docker hub repository?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to push a docker image to a private repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28349392/how-to-push-a-docker-image-to-a-private-repository)

Comment: If you mean to push the image to your Docker Hub, try updating `image` -> `repository` in module.json to `your-docker-hub-user-name/repo-name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find the correct URL for dockerhub, but Azure Container Registry was able to resolve my problem.

Details of the URL are here: [Raspberry PI / IOTEdge failing to pull from Azure Container Registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54449612/raspberry-pi-iotedge-failing-to-pull-from-azure-container-registry)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
docker push <hub-user>/<repo-name>:<tag>
```

i.e

```
docker push username/reponame:latest
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `docker login` first. Then build image  `docker build -t <docker_hub_username>/<app_name>:<tag>` and then just push `docker push <docker_hub_username>/<app_name>:<tag>`. You don't need to specify any specific URL for Docker Hub.