# Raspberry PI / IOTEdge failing to pull from Azure Container Registry

Tags: raspberry-pi, azure-iot-edge, azure-container-registry, microsoft-custom-vision

I have an IOTEdge device (Rapi3) and IotEdgeHub and IotEdgeagent are deployed and running.

I have successfully built and deployed images ([custom-vision example](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/Custom-vision-service-iot-edge-raspberry-pi)) to ACR and have configured Access Keys in the portal. I've added the respective credentials to my `.env` file.

The `deployment.json` has been deployed using `Create deployment for single device`.

Within IotAgent logs I can see a series of `500` errors:

> Executing command for operation ["create"] failed.
>   Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Agent.Edgelet.EdgeletCommunicationException-
>   Message:Error calling Create module camera-capture: Could not create
>   module camera-capture      caused by: Could not pull image
>   myregistryname.azurecr.io/azurev1/cameracapture:0.2.7-arm32v7      caused
>   by: Get
>   https://myregistryname.azurecr.io/v2/azurev1/cameracapture/manifests/0.2.7-arm32v7:
>   unauthorized: authentication required, StatusCode:500

I have already run `sudo docker login -u myregistryname -p accesskeypassword1 myregistryname.azurecr.io/azurev1` successfully

I can run `sudo docker pull myregistryname.azurecr.io/azurev1/cameracapture:0.2.7-arm32v7` manually which successfully download the respective image.

It would appear that IotEdgeHub and/or IotEdgeAgent doesn't have the same access to the ACR. How can I elevate the privileges.

---

**Update**; my `deployment.template.json` file is as follows:

```
{
  "moduleContent": {
    "$edgeAgent": {
      "properties.desired": {
        "schemaVersion": "1.0",
        "runtime": {
          "type": "docker",
          "settings": {
            "minDockerVersion": "v1.25",
            "loggingOptions": "",
            "registryCredentials": {
              "registryName": {
                "username": "$CONTAINER_REGISTRY_USERNAME",
                "password": "$CONTAINER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD",
                "address": "$CONTAINER_REGISTRY_ADDRESS"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "systemModules": {
          "edgeAgent": {
            "type": "docker",
            "settings": {
              "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/azureiotedge-agent:1.0",
              "createOptions": ""
            }
          },
          "edgeHub": {
            "type": "docker",
            "status": "running",
            "restartPolicy": "always",
            "settings": {
              "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/azureiotedge-hub:1.0",
              "createOptions": ""
            },
            "env": {
                "OptimizeForPerformance": {
                  "value": "false"
                }
            }
          }
        },
        "modules": {
          "camera-capture": {
            "version": "1.0",
            "type": "docker",
            "status": "running",
            "restartPolicy": "always",
            "env": {
              "VIDEO_PATH": {"value": 0},
              "IMAGE_PROCESSING_ENDPOINT":  {"value": "http://image-classifier-service:80/image"},
              "RESIZE_WIDTH":  {"value": 256},
              "RESIZE_HEIGHT":  {"value": 256},
              "SHOW_VIDEO":  {"value": "True"}
            },
            "settings": {
              "image": "${MODULES.CameraCapture.arm32v7}",
              "createOptions": {
                "HostConfig": {
                  "PortBindings": {
                    "5012/tcp": [ { "HostPort":"5012"}]
                  },
                  "Binds": ["/dev/video0:/dev/video0"],
                  "Devices":[{"PathOnHost":"/dev/video0","PathInContainer":"/dev/video0","CgroupPermissions":"mrw"}]
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "sensehat-display": {
            "version": "1.0",
            "type": "docker",
            "status": "running",
            "restartPolicy": "always",
            "env": {
              "THRESHOLD": {"value": 0.6}
            },
            "settings": {
              "image": "${MODULES.SenseHatDisplay.arm32v7}",
              "createOptions": {
                "HostConfig":{
                  "Binds":["/dev/i2c1:/dev/i2c1"],
                  "Privileged":true
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "image-classifier-service": {
            "version": "1.0",
            "type": "docker",
            "status": "running",
            "restartPolicy": "always",
            "settings": {
              "image": "${MODULES.ImageClassifierService.arm32v7}",
              "createOptions": ""
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "$edgeHub": {
      "properties.desired": {
        "schemaVersion": "1.0",
        "routes": {
          "CameraCaptureToSenseHatDisplay": "FROM /messages/modules/camera-capture/outputs/output1 INTO BrokeredEndpoint(\"/modules/sensehat-display/inputs/input1\")",
          "CameraCaptureToIoTHub": "FROM /messages/modules/camera-capture/outputs/output1 INTO $upstream",
          "CameraCaptureGAToIoTHub": "FROM /messages/modules/CameraCaptureGA/outputs/* INTO $upstream"
        },
        "storeAndForwardConfiguration": {
          "timeToLiveSecs": 7200
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Settings as displayed in the portal:
[image]

Comment: In the generated `deployment.json`, are the credentials filled in the `registryCredentials` section in plaintext?

Comment: I did have `registryName` but have changed that to `registryCredentials` and still the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `deployment.json` that gets send to the device should look like this (if you do use the ACR admin credentials and not the recommended [service principle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-authentication#service-principal)):

```
"registryCredentials": {
    "registryName": {
        "username": "myregistryname",
        "password": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "address": "myregistryname.azurecr.io"
     }
 }
```

Can you confirm your deployment.json looks like this?

Comment: I have added a screenshot of my settings. I'll try removing the `/azurev1` suffix on the address to see if that helps things move along.

Comment: Yep, that was it - I didn't need the `/azurev1` on my URL