# Failed to connect to my raspberry pi3 model B using Universal Authentication

Tags: c#, uwp, visual-studio-2019, raspberry-pi3, remote-debugging

I am new member, I was looking for a solution for my problem.

I have installed on my SD card `IoT v.10.0.17763.107` on RPi 3, and It boots good.

![enter image description here][1]

I can also see the device on Dashboard, and Device portal, working from `Windows 10 Pro version 1909, OS Version 18363.900`.

[image]

I developed an UWP project blinky led, [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Kr5E.png)
however the following issues are observed:

Visual Studio 2019, Universal application, identifies my remote system,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMnvF.png); but rejects to deploy in following configurations

- ARM with Universal (Unencrypted Protocol):

```
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error DEP6957: Failed to connect to device '192.168.1.3' using Universal Authentication. Please verify the correct remote authentication mode is specified in the project debug settings. COMException - Exception from HRESULT: 0x801C0003 [0x801C0003]
```

- ARM - Windows/None mode:

```
Error: Unable to connect to the Microsoft Visual Studio Remote Debugger . The Visual Studio 2019 Remote Debugger (MSVSMON.EXE) does not appear to be running on the remote computer. This may be because a firewall is preventing communication to the remote computer. Please see Help for assistance on configuring remote debugging.
```

I don t know how to resolve this problem. I will be so thankfull if someone could help me.

Update:
This is what I have when I search the port 8117; zeyneb is my raspberry's name
[image]

For your question about reject deployement, I mean when I choose in authentification: universel(...)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYNSj.png) I get Error 1(as mentionad above) ; In the normal case when you select this mode everything should run

Update:
netstat on from the other
[image]
[image]

Update :

[image]

Comment: Your smart card is encrypted and you cannot use Unencrypted Protocol.  When debugging a smart card I always recommend first unlocking the card in windows.  The card will stay unlocked.  Then write c# code to read and write card to make sure you are using correct mode.   There are lots of modes like 8 bit, 16 bit, 32 bit (address and data combinations).  Then after you ca read/write then write code in c# to unlock card.

Comment: I don t have problem in my card, it works well, I have a problem in remote debugging between visual studio and my raspberry

Comment: What is remote debugging?  I think you are debugging by making a HTTPS (secure) connection to the raspberry operating system remotely.  So you need a SSL/TLS authentication.  I think the console (Portal) you are seeing the error message is an RS-232 connection (or non secure TCP).  I think the WCP is secure from Windows even though the raspberry in not secure.

Comment: Did you do everything on following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/deploying-and-debugging-uwp-apps

Comment: Yes I did everything, when I click deploy nothing runs

Comment: I think what you mean is the raspberry boots since you see messages on the console but you cannot remotely connect to raspberry on UWP.  If you use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler you should see the SSL/TLS authentification (using TCP) and then a http request and a response.  The status in the response if good would be a 200 OK, but if bad the status would be something else.  We need to see if the TCP is occurring and then then if http seen (or https) and the return status.  Also capturing with sniff the Windows response so we can see the differences.

Comment: Try following troubleshooting : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/troubleshooting

Comment: I edit my answer to clarify well my probem

Comment: You should be able from cmd.exe >Netstat -a see the connection status for the port 8117.  Is the raspberry not starting or is the issue connecting the debugger?  I'm not sure what you mean by "rejects to deploy in following configurations".  Can you give more details on what is not happening.

Comment: I edited my answer

Comment: It looks like netstat has IP 192.168.1.4 establish using port 5985 and your are failing 192.168.1.3.  Which is the correct IP?  Do you have port set to default 8117 or 5985?  Why two connections to 5985?  Can you run Netstat from oether end?

Comment: Any idea why you have the TIME-WAIT?  The TIME-WAIT will prevent another connection to same IP/Port.

Comment: On my rasp I have 192.168.1.6

Comment: Why does error say "192.168.1.3".  Can you ping from cmd.exe >Ping 192.168.1.6?  Netstat isn't showing a connection to 192.168.1.6.  You can also check ARP table from cmd.exe >ARP -A .  ARP is protocol that PIN uses and when a machine is turned on it will send an ARP that will show up on all the other machines in the subnet.  The ARP is sent by every machine ~1/2 hour and will timeout after 1 hour.

Comment: For192.168.1.3 I was just wrong sorry . I updated my answer to show netstat from rasp

Comment: Looks like you are just failing the login.  See following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54449612/raspberry-pi-iotedge-failing-to-pull-from-azure-container-registry

Comment: @Zeyneb there isn't any image in link 1??

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below steps to troubleshoot the issue.

1. Check the port 8117 on your device can be accessed, when you use remote debug, the defaut port of msvsmon.exe is 8117.
2. Check the remote debugger can be lauched on your device.
   [image]
3. Copy the remote debugger tool from your development PC to Windows IoT Core. You may find the application here:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 16.0\Common7\IDE\Remote
> Debugger\arm

Folder path in Windows IoT Core:

> C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\VSRemoteTools\arm

Update 2:
This is what it shows when I look for 8117 port in powershell
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgAhV.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrIMj.png)

Comment: Hi, @Zeyneb, your command can not filter the port 8117, you need to use `netstat -a | Select-String "8117"`. If the msvsmon could not be launched in your device, it is obviously that the port could not open. So in the step 2 about, you can start the remote debugger manually, but the port is 8116.

Comment: You can open the remote debug via [Device Portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/manage-your-device/deviceportal), like above image in my post.

Comment: When I click start it gives me this msg: Failed to start the Visual Studio Remote Debugger. The Remote Debugger needs to be copied to the device. This can be done by deploying an application to the device using Visual Studio.

Comment: I think I have problems because on my raspberry I don't have msvsmon.exe: how can I add it please ?

Comment: @Zeyneb, i updated my response again. The step 3 shows how to add the proccess in you Windows IoT Core manually.