# unable to deploy local container image to k8s cluster

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, containers, kubernetes-pod, container-image

I have tried to deploy one of the local container images I created but keeps always getting the below error

> Failed to pull image "webrole1:dev": rpc error: code = Unknown desc =
>   Error response from daemon: pull access denied for webrole1,
>   repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied:
>   requested access to

I have followed the below article to containerize my application and I was able to successfully complete this but when I try to deploy it to k8s pod I don't succeed

My pod.yaml looks like below

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: learnk8s
spec:
  containers:
  - name: webrole1dev
    image: 'webrole1:dev'
    ports:
      - containerPort: 8080
```

and below are some images from my PowerShell

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am new to dockers and k8s so thanks for the help in advance and would appreciate if I get some detailed response.

Answer (score 1):

When you're working locally, you can use an image name like `webrole`, however that doesn't tell Docker where the image came from (because it didn't come from anywhere, you built it locally). When you start working with multiple hosts, you need to push things to a Docker registry. For local Kubernetes experiments you can also change your config so you build your image in the same Docker environment as Kubernetes is using, though the specifics of that depend on how you set up both Docker and Kubernetes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I am new to dockers and k8s so can you please help me with an article about how can I deploy this image to a public repository

Comment: If you have another question not necessairly related to the one you have posted I advice you to post it as separate one on stackoverflow - that is a proper way to use it.  Speaking about pushing image to docker registry - here is solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28349392/how-to-push-a-docker-image-to-a-private-repository - only difference is that your repository is not marked as private, but steps are the same.