# Docker Hub Repository

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-registry

Can we push different multiple images to same docker hub repository?

For example:
I have 2 images Mysql and ubuntu and only one repository name is demo.
I want to push mysql and ubuntu image to demo repository.
How can we achieve this?

Comment: you can use tags to separate between images, call them demo:mysql, demo:ubuntu. Although yo should have different repositories one for mysql and one for ubuntu

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28349392/how-to-push-a-docker-image-to-a-private-repository

Comment: You can have multiple images, each with their own tag sets on docker hub. If your username is 'swapnil', you can have `swapnil/database:latest` and `swapnil/ubuntu:20.04` for instance. More info here https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/repos/#pushing-a-docker-container-image-to-docker-hub

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

consider to do it in this way (works on my side):

```
docker image tag your_image_name:version your_account_name_dockerhub/image_name:version

docker image push your_account_name_dockerhub/image_name:version
```

for example:

```
docker image tag nginx:latest myname/nginx:latest
docker image push myname/nginx:latest
```